# Send food via tap -- what does it mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I've just came across the following sentence "Send food direct to houses **via taps** for those times when you don't want to cook."

I know what is tap, but cannot imagine food going through it. Is it me or does this sentence sound really weird?

Comment: What's the context?  It does sound weird, but it's hard to be sure without more context.

Comment: This looks like one of those futuristic _"innovative ideas"_. If that is the case, the sentence looks pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: No context, that's just a separate sentence from SpeakOut Students' Book (Upper Intermediate) p.64 ex.1B

Comment: Yep, @VarunKN that's probably it. This appeared to be the section on innovation. Still rather weird ^^

Comment: Possibly "taps" on your smartphone, in the context of online food ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Not all foods are solid.

Applesauce, any number of cheeses which are fluid given a bit of heat, and ice cream all spring immediately to mind. And that's ignoring the fact that any solid object smaller than the spigot being used as part of the tap can be transmitted this way, such as corn, peanuts, sunflower seeds, and most grains.

In fact, such a service might be welcome and useful in certain areas. For example, imagine you're living in a place like Japan where rice is a staple of their diet; having a tap that dispenses rice in your kitchen would be quite the convenience.

But, to your original comment, I have to agree that the sentence sounds weird.

Comment: Note the connection to beer being "on tap", or available at a faucet.